# Maze background algorithm ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a big problem.
I would like to create a maze. I can create a maze paths, but player can't walk in this maze paths. 
I have created random maze paths algorithm.

Algorithm of drawing a maze look

```
>   var maze_draw:Sprite = new  (...)<br>
maze_draw.graphics.lineStyle(2,0xff0000);
            maze_draw.graphics.moveTo(10,10);
            maze_draw.graphics.lineTo(10+wall_size*maze_width,10);
            maze_draw.graphics.lineTo(10+wall_size*maze_width,10+wall_size*maze_height);
            maze_draw.graphics.lineTo(10,10+wall_size*maze_height);
            maze_draw.graphics.lineTo(10,10);
```

This is the method of maze drawing.But my player can't enter into my maze. This maze look like a square with some background. But I didnt create any background but lines only. This is my collision method:

```
> if (e.keyCode==40){
        guy.y+=5;

        if (guy.hitTestObject(maze_draw)){
            guy.y-=5;

        }
```

When player will go into invisible wall, he can't go on...
How can I create maze and maze collision, when ma player can go into ma maze??
Sorry for my English...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should go to this [site](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/11/26/the-basics-of-pathfinding-animated-example/). This is just one of his great tutorials. If this is not what you search for, he also has many other tutorials about mazes.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: I thought this would be better because the actual answer was going to be very long and I cant explain it better and shorter than the tutorial i linked to... but i try to make it better next time.